# jQuery returns [object HTMLInputElement] instead of string from .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am using jQuery to generate some input fields and buttons on the fly. I provide an ID attributes for these elements, which are also dynamically generated using an algorithm:

```
// Where menuItem is a string (ex. 'Child Admission' -> 'Child_AdmissionQuantity')
var quantityId = menuItem.replace(' ', '_') + 'Quantity';
```

I then use the same algorithm to select the field using jQuery and attempt to get the value of the input field:

```
// Get Reference to the quantity field
    var quantityId = '#' + menuItem.replace(' ', '_') + 'Quantity';
    console.log("quantityId: " + quantityId);

    // Get the Value of the field
    var quantity = $(quantityId).val();
```

Instead of returning a string, jQuery returns a [object HTMLInputElement].

Here is how I create the form fields:

```
function processMenuItem(menuItem) {
    // Generate a quantityId
    var quantityId = menuItem.replace(' ', '_') + 'Quantity';
    console.log("menuItem: " + menuItem + "\n"
                    + "quantityId: " + quantityId + "\n");

    // Generate a Menu Item Option
    var menuItemOption = '<div class="product">'
                            + '<div class="productName">' + menuItem + '</div>'
                            + '<div class="quantity">'
                            + '<input type="text" name="quantity" id="' + quantityId + '" placeholder="2" />'
                            + '</div>'
                            + '<button type="button" onclick="addItem(\'' + menuItem + '\')">Add Item</button>'
                            + '</div><!-- End of .product -->';

    // Add the Option to the Menu
    $('#displayMenu').append(menuItemOption);
}
```

I need the actual value for form processing, anyone know a work around?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share some more details about the problem... because it should work fine... can you log the value of `$(quantityId)` and see what is logged

Comment: "quantityId: #Child_AdmissionQuantity" - A direct copy from the Console. Output in HTML: "Child Admission - [object HTMLInputElement]"

Comment: Do you get the same value using native APIs -- `document.querySelector(qualtityId).value`?

Comment: @Matt I was asking about `console.log($(quantityId), $(quantityId).get())` - the result of the selector seems to be fine....

Comment: oh ok, I'll try that now.

Comment: @Matt seems fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fth716vw/1/

Comment: The $(quantityId).get() gives me a console object that does display the proper 'value' attribute but I don't know how to access it

Comment: @Matt the above attached fiddle seems to be working fine... can you try to recreate the issue there

Comment: Thanks, figured it out. Error elsewhere.